# Magento 2 : How to Display Larger Number of Products Than 999

Tags: magento2, product

I need to display over 4000 products on one page.

Unfortunately, in Magento I can set a maximum of 999. How to change it?

[image]

Comment: John, I want display all product in admin panel (backend) - no in fronend for customers.

Comment: Sylvester, apologies I misread the question! I understand what you mean, the bit you circle occurs at the bottom of my product pages for customers and so i got confused, sorry